# Importing GeoPackage into GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geopackage

I've created a geopackage through gdal_translate (overviews with gdaladdo)

In geoserver 2.13/2.15 I can create the geopackage store with no problems, but then geoseverver won't fetch the tables/layers from the geopackage.

[image]

This is the geopackage gdalinfo

```
 Driver: GPKG/GeoPackage
Files: ortos2017.gpkg
Size is 133333, 133333
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / Portugal TM06",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",39.66825833333333],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-8.133108333333334],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3763"]]
Origin = (-33600.000000000000000,83000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.120000000000000,-0.120000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  IDENTIFIER=ortos2017
  ZOOM_LEVEL=10
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -33600.000,   83000.000) (  8d31'44.35"W, 40d24'54.32"N)
Lower Left  (  -33600.000,   67000.040) (  8d31'41.32"W, 40d16'15.61"N)
Upper Right (  -17600.040,   83000.000) (  8d20'25.71"W, 40d24'56.09"N)
Lower Right (  -17600.040,   67000.040) (  8d20'24.12"W, 40d16'17.37"N)
Center      (  -25600.020,   75000.020) (  8d26' 3.88"W, 40d20'35.99"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 66667x66667, 33333x33333, 16667x16667, 8333x8333, 4167x4167, 2083x2083, 1042x1042, 521x521
```

What am I missing? Do I have to add other attributes to the gpkg?

Comment: Did you configure the GeoPackage (Mosaic) store https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/geopkg.html?

Comment: well I feel so dumb! I was using Geopackage (vector).
But now geoserver throws an error publishing the layer

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected, cannot find a reader for the current tile image format

Comment: just tried a geoserver 2.15 instance and it worked. The difference for the 2.13 instance is that the later doesn't have the gdal extension enabled.

Comment: please add this as an answer for the benefit of future searchers

Answer (score -2):

Seems GeoServer needs gdal extension for importing a layer from a GeoPackage (Mosaic) store